# Integrating RapidMiner JAR libraries into Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rapidminer

I am trying to integrate JAR libraries of RapidMiner into android app, but i got 1 error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I'm using Android 5.1, multiDex is enabled.

```
 public void runRapidMiner(){
    RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(RapidMiner.ExecutionMode.COMMAND_LINE);
    RapidMiner.init();
    Process process = null;
    try {
        process = new Process(new File("/home/patrik/Plocha/mojSrom.rmp"));
        process.run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperatorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility, how can i successfully run this code?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might have implemented many library file, either you can reduce them by removing unused library from gradle (or) by setting the multidex to true, below code explains how to do it.

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "applicationId"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        //****Multidex ****
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed unused libraries from project, but there is another RUNTIME error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

for class: Ljavax/swing/JComponent and if i turn off/on my app, then appears the error for class: com.rapidminer.tools.I18N (this class is in my external library, i can create an object of this class)  [image]
[image]